# Stop regex from removing decimal points

Tags: c#, regex, replace

In my equation, I'm trying to remove the first word that appears after a specific word that I have mentioned in the regex code. For example:

In the sentence:

> Hello my name is Roger

I'm extracting the word "Roger" with this regex:

```
Regex reg3 = new Regex("is\\s\\w+");
MatchCollection match3 = reg3.Matches(result);
foreach (Match match in match3)
{
    var val = match.Value;
    val = val.Replace("is", "");
    val = val.Trim();
}
```

But in a case such as this:

> My answer is 3.05

and when I apply the same regex, I end up with this:

> 3

That is because the regex removes all characters after the "is", how do I change the regex so that it  in a case such as what I mentioned above, it keeps the `decimal` number as it is and prints 3.05?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you always wanting the final word after 'is'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stops after printing the first number because the following `.` is not a word character. To match also the literal dot, you need to put `\w` and `.` inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
Regex reg3 = new Regex("is\\s[.\\w]+");
```

OR

```
Regex reg3 = new Regex(@"is\s[.\w]+");
```

Comment: to match all the non-space characters `@"is\s\S+"`